# Submitting values through action and onclick

Tags: html, button, onclick, submit, action

can we use action and onclick in same form through same button?

`<form action="welcome.php" method="post"><br/>`

`<input type="submit" style="height:25px;width:85px;" value="Login" onclick="getdata(n.value,p.value);">`

`</form>`

Comment: If you wish to do some pre-processing `onclick` before taking `action` then consider using `onbeforesubmit` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can submit `forms` on this way also:

HTML:

```
<form id="myform" method="post">

User:<input type="text" name="user"><br>
Password:<input type="text" name="pasw"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Login">

</form>
```

---

Do a JQuery file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#myform').submit(function(){
var data="user="+$('#user').val()+"&passw="+$('#passw').val();
$.post('welcome.php',data,function(data){
   alert(data);//This will show you a response from your welcome.php
});
return false;
});

});
```

---

Welcome.php

```
<?php
$user=$_POST['user'];
$passw=$_POST['passw'];

echo "Welcome $user, your password is $passw";//Your response
?>
```

(: